# Setting Date.today to use Time.zone?

Tags: ruby, date, activesupport

Since `Date.today` uses the system time, what's the best way possible to have
it return the same thing as `Time.zone.now.to_date`, assuming `Time.zone` is
set?

I know I can override the Date class, but wasn't sure if there was some other
Ruby convention I'm missing since I'm sure I'm not the first person to
encounter this problem.

Comment: Please add some examples showing why this is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re looking for [`Date.current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current), which calls `Time.zone.today` if `Time.zone` is set. This is `Date`’s equivalent of [`Time.current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-current) (there’s also [`DateTime.current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-c-current)).

Also remember that none of these methods are in Ruby core, but are instead provided by ActiveSupport.